# How to adding or update more file to github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2022

I'm new on GitHub.
I've been finished my code using Visual Studio 2022. Also I did create and upload my files to GitHub, but I have a mistake and need to edit some code on one my controller. I confused how to upload my file to the existing folder on GitHub.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want to update an existing file on your repository?

Comment: yes. I did create my repository but i dont know how to add the file to my repository. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your Visual Studio project is connected to your GitHub.
2. If you edit some code on you Visual Studio project and want to update it on your GitHub. Go to **Git** on your top left corner.
3. Then click on **Commit or Stash**.
4. Now, on your left side, there should be a new popup box that shows the file(s) you edited on.
5. Click **Commit All**, make sure you add some comments on what you've changed.
6. Finally, clicked the up arrow **Push**. Then the new changes should be showing on your GitHub

Answer (score 0):

To add new file you can follow following steps:

1. Open home page of your repository
2. On the right side of it you will find a option to "Add file" which will have 2 dropdown.From that you can simply select "upload files".
3. By clicking on "Upload Files", you will be given option to upload file by browing or by drag and drop.
4. There will be option to add comment regarding your file changes if you want to add.you can upload that file to current branch, otherwise you can add new branch and upload it there.
5. At the end, click on commit changes.